# "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed" using ORAOLEDB, IIS7, 32bit app, 64bit o/s

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, oracle11g

I have a classic ASP application which I've moved from a Windows 2003 server running IIS6.0 to 64-bit Windows 2008 R2 running IIS7. In IIS7 I've created a website and added an application to that and have set the application pool to enable 32-bit applications.

The application connects to an Oracle database using the ORAOLEDB driver - I've installed the 64-bit Oracle client 11.2.0.3 to connect to the backend Oracle 11g database and can connect fine via the same user as the application using SQLPlus.

When I run the application though, its attempt to connect to Oracle fails with the IIS logs showing the error:

> "Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed"

I've tried various possible things to try and get this working:

- registering OraOLEDB11.dll manually
- disabling 32-bit applications from the app pool
- using the 32-bit drivers instead both with 32-bits apps enabled and disabled
- reinstalling the drivers completely and trying all the above

So far without any luck. The asp code connects as follows:

```
objOracleConnection.CursorLocation = adUseClient
objOracleConnection.ConnectionString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=MYDATASOURCE;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;PLSQLRSet=1;OLE DB Services=-2;"
objOracleConnection.Open
```

**EDIT:** I've tried a simple VBS script (using essentially the same code as above) to connect and it gets the same error, so IIS may not be the problem. The exact same script works on the Windows 2003 box however.

I've reinstalled the Oracle client via the 'Troubleshoot Compatibility' option, indicating that the application works under Windows 2003 SP1 but still get the same issue from both the VBS script and the IIS application :(

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess, but enabling 32 bit applications in IIS7 seems to disable 64 bit applications.  If it's a 64 bit driver you may need to disable 32 bit in your app pool

Comment: Thanks John - I've tried all combinations unfortunately e.g. 32-bit app pool with 32 bit drivers, 32-bit app pool with 64-bit drivers, etc. but still get the error.

Note my edit above, I get the same problem from VB script so IIS may be a bit of a red herring.